# How can I see the Path or Ancestors in a large json file

Tags: json, atom-editor

I am working with a very large json file, in Atom, I want to know if there is a way to see the json path of where my cursor is at but can't find a package to help me

For example, if my cursor is at Y below, I want something which says
grandparent2:parent:child

I do not wish to collapse all the json to see this.

If Atom cannot help is there another editor which can?

```
{
  "grandparent" : {
    "parent" : {
      "child" : {
        "property" : "X"
      }
    }
  }
  "grandparent2" : {
    "parent" : {
      "child" : {
        "property" : "Y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer json editor(https://jsoneditoronline.org/). See the example below and click on node and you will see the path:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.e461c68e9a9c491781169eeac7b651da&right=local.qefaya

It will look like [image]

Comment: This works for me, I am hoping that something else exists offline or in Atom